# Size of structure and structure pointer: C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a structure as shown below

```
struct Node
{
int data;
Node* next; 
}
```

and an array of pointers to this Node structure

```
struct Node *list[10];
list[0]=(struct Node*)mal?loc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Here while allocating memory to the first element of list, Did i really need `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`? I have this doubt because it provides the size of a structure and what i need is size of structure addressd to store its adress(struture pointer's size) less than 4B?. Please explain.

Comment: Are you sure that you would like to use c-style arrays over `std::vector<Node*>`?

Comment: You want the size of the thing you are getting memory for

Comment: "it provides the size of a structure and what i need is size of structure pointer"... Well, only you know what you *need*. If you really need size of structure pointer then calculate size of structure pointer. End of story. However, I don't see why you'd need "size of structure pointer" here. Even though I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, it appears that you actually need size of a structure here.

Comment: I think am quite fortunate in having grown up and acquire an interest in CS back in the 8-bit days, where you could take your Commodore 64 and know everything that there is to know about it, how it works, and how computers work on a fundamental level, including these kind of basic, elementary concepts. It's quite disappointing to see people who never had the benefit of actually understanding how CPU and RAM work struggle with what looks to me like simple, fundamental, basic, concepts.

Comment: @AnT since the elements in array stores the address of structure, i need the size of structure address, not the size of structure.

Comment: @HariKrishnan no you don't. Enough space for pointers is already allocated in every element of the array. You just need to allocate space for the whole structure for each element, because you are setting each pointer to point to a structure.

Comment: @Hari Krishnan: Um... No. You don't need to allocate memory for array elements (which indeed are pointers). It is already allocated by `struct Node *list[10];`. Nothing else needs to be done for the pointers themselves. Now you are allocating memory for the *structs* these pointers will **point to**. These pointers will point to whole structs. So, you need to allocate memory for whole structs.

Comment: @AnT Ok. now i got it. thanks .:)

Comment: It is not clear though what language you are trying to use: C or C++. If this is supposed to be C++, you can use `Node` instead of `struct Node` and `new` instead of `malloc`. If this is supposed to be C, then don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: If this is supposed to be C, then stop casting the result of malloc// why? i can't get it

Comment: Because in C you can assign a `void*` to any other type of pointer. But not in C++.

Answer (score 3):

> Did i really need `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` ?

Yes. That is correct.

`list[0]` is of type `Node*`. It can point to an object of type `Node`. Hence, you need to allocate enough memory to hold an object of type `Node` to be able point `list[0]` to it. Using `sizeof(struct Node)` as argument to `malloc` gives you that.

However, there are couple of things you can change to make your program more like a C++ program and less like a C program.

1. You don't need to use `struct Node`. You can use just `Node`.
2. Don't use `malloc`. User the `new` operator.

---

```
Node *list[10];
list[0]= new Node;
```

Comment: but where i am struggling is, since list is an array of pointers, each of its elements will store an address. So we need to allocate memory to save  that address only rigt? why shoud we allocate memory for the whole structure instead of its addreess's size? size of Nodes address will be always less than size of the Node ryt?

Comment: @HariKrishnan, *So we need to allocate memory to save that address only right?* No. `list` is an array of pointers. It can store the addresses without needing any more dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: "*So we need to allocate memory to save that address only rigt?*" - you already did, when you allocated the `list[]` array. It already has enough allocated memory to hold the actual pointers. "*why shoud we allocate memory for the whole structure instead of its addreess's size?*" - because the `list[]` array contains pointers that point at `Node` objects, so you have to allocate the full `Node` size for each pointer to point at.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node *list[10];
list[0]=(struct Node*)mal?loc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

`list[0]` is going to store a pointer to some memory which will store `Node`.You use `malloc` to allocate memory, so you have to tell `malloc` how much memory you need to allocate.In return `malloc` gives you a pointer to that allocated memory.